# WinError -2146893813 when trying to az login for terraform workflow

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to login to my Azure tenant/subscription using the "az login" command but, suddenly keep getting the following error:

**terraform Decryption failed: [WinError -2146893813] Key not valid for use in specified state.**

I upgraded Windows 10 to 11 yesterday so I guess probably this issue is related to my OS upgrade?

Comment: Ensure that your **Windows 11** installation is up to date by checking for and installing any pending Windows updates. Additionally, try resetting the **Azure CLI configuration** :`az logout` and `az account clear`, and then log in again with `az login`. If the issue persists, you can temporarily turn off token cache encryption : `az config set core.encrypt_token_cache=false`. If the problem still persists after performing these steps, consider **reinstalling Azure CLI** using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli#install-or-update)

Comment: If still not working after performing all above steps: Try deleting **.Azure** folder in path **C:\Users\yourusername**.   [**find the folder**](https://i.imgur.com/9JI1CiL.png)

Comment: @VenkatV the deletion of .azure was also mentioned in a few other forums but, I was a bit reluctant to do so. Deleting 2 files in that folder actually worked! By the way, thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

After looking at multiple pages all over internet,

Tried all of the below steps:

1. `az upgrade` = Failed. (shows required az cli is up-to-date)
2. `az config set core.encrypt_token_cache=false` = Failed (Tried to run this command, still did not work)
3. Tried to delete two files in the `.azure` folder of  = Failed

   - My Windows home folder `C:\Users\My_UserName\`
   - The files I had to delete were the following:

   ```
   "msal_http_cache.bin ; msal_token_cache.bin "
   ```
4. After deleting the `.azure` folder in `C:\Users\My_UserName\.azure`, this error got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I managed to get the issue resolved by deleting 2 files in the .azure folder of my Windows home folder **C:\Users\My_UserName\ .azure**. The files I had to delete were the following.

1. msal_http_cache.bin
2. msal_token_cache.bin

After deleting the above 2 files, I managed to log in to Azure using "az login" again.